# Copy constructor, destructor and assignment operator. When don't we need them all?

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor, standards, assignment-operator

I know the C++ rule of thumb when you add cctor, dtor or op= to your class, you need to add the other two too to make you class work properly under all circumstances.

Are there any case when you don't need to provide all the three, just one or two of them?

Why don't the C++ require you to add them all if you add one of them to your class?

EDIT1:

You mentioned examples when you not only don't need some of them, but you don't want to have them so you want to make them private or protected. But you still need to write them in your code even with empty bodies.

The only valid reason for me not having them all when you make a class polimorphic by adding a virtual destructor with empty body. But as soon as you write something in the destructor's body, you should consider writing something in the body of the cctor and op= too.

I'm looking for examples when you don't need to write all 3 methods and you can omit some of them without causing bugs in your class even if a newbie are using your class. :)

Answer (score 5):

One case in which you may want to use a destructor without a copy constructor or assignment operator is when developing a polymorphic class, in which case you want a `virtual` destructor to allow deallocation through a base class pointer.  These classes often will support copy constructors in order to facilitate the "virtual clone" idiom.  However, they rarely have assignment operators, since polymorphic classes are usually heap-allocated and referenced only through pointers, in which case direct assignment almost always leads to slicing.

Comment: I would add that to protect from slicing, you'd better make the copy constructor protected.

Comment: For polimorphic classes you may want to make op= private or protected too.

Answer (score 3):

Observed classes (those that report their lifetimes to another class) require all constructors and destructor, but not op=. C++ doesn't require them because it would be completely unnecessary- we, the programmers, know best.

In addition, you may want destructor but not the other two if you have a non-copyable class.

Comment: If you really want to make a type non-copyable, you may still want to write the cctor and op= as private or protected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write them all if you have pointers or sth like that in your class so there will be no shallow copy in the copy cctor or op=, and no memory leak in dtor.

This is one case where you should write them all, other cases exist in other answers.

C++ doesn't require them all because it writes default ones, and because they may not be neseccary.

Comment: The question was to demonstrate cases where they're not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you want to change the access rights, or in the case of
the destructor, make it virtual.  Declaring a private copy constructor
or assignment operator is a classical way of banning these operations,
even if you don't need a destructor; any time you want to derive from
a class, the destructor should be virtual (or protected); and if you
want to forbid anything but dynamically allocated instances, the classic
idiom is to declare the destructor private, and implement a destruct
function which does `delete this` to get rid of the object.

Finally, the compiler generated versions are inline, and you might want
to declare one of these functions to prevent it from being inline.  (In
days of smaller memory, this was often a consideration.)